# Determine the value of a - Statistics

Tags: statistics

> Given X = {80, 320, a, a, a, a,} and that mean = 100, determine the
>   value of a.

Would appreciate help with this question, really stuck on this one.

Thanks!

Comment: $100 = \frac{2}{3}\left(100 + a \right)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the average of a collection of numbers, you add up the numbers and divide by the number of numbers there are.

$Average(a,b,c,d) = \frac{a+b+c+d}{4}$ for example.

The fact that one of these numbers appearing in your problem is an unknown variable does not in any way change the definition of taking an average of them.

The numbers are $80,320,a,a,a,a$.  There are six numbers in all (some of them unknown).

The average of them then is $\frac{80+320+a+a+a+a}{6}$

We are told that the average is $100$, so that tells us $100=\frac{80+320+a+a+a+a}{6}$.  From here it is just a matter of rearranging numbers and variables so that you get an equation $a=\square$ after some algebraic simplifications.